# I need help evaluating the following improper integral

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan(x^2)}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x$$
Since it doesn't have a antiderivative in terms of elementary functions I cannot rely on the fundamental theorem of calculus. I tried using the Feynman integration technique by adding an extra parameter inside the inverse tangent but the expression after differentiation under the integral sign got so convoluted that I don't think it would've led to the solution. I would appreciate any help!

Comment: this may help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1413507/solve-this-integral-int-0-infty-frac-arctan-xxx21-mathrm-dx

Comment: Also note: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/287724/509159 and

Comment: Are you sure that your integral converges?

Comment: Hint: Use the change of variable $t=1/x$ and the fact that for $u>0$, $arctan)(u)+ arctan(1/u)=\pi/2$.

Comment: A more general result for $\alpha\in \mathbb {R} $ is: $$\int_0^{\infty} \frac {\arctan(x^{\alpha})}{1+x^2}~dx=\frac {\pi^2}{8} $$

Comment: @projectilemotion Could you provide a proof of this result?

Comment: @Sz.Akos Using Kelenner's hint, you can prove the more general result.

Comment: @Kelenner Thank you so much, I got it.

Comment: @projectilemotion Yes, I just realized it. Thank you all!